# Fetch data without using union all every month

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2016

```
Select * from [dbo].[TRNS0119]
union all
Select * from [dbo].[TRNS0219]
union all
Select * from [dbo].[TRNS0319]
union all
Select * from [dbo].[TRNS0419]
```

In my attendance SQL Server database, every month a new table gets created with in/out records. I have to use `union all` to fetch data from all 12 month's data. I want to my query to fetch data automatically when new table gets created with a particular name. I am not SA user so can not make any changes / triggers / procedures.

So far I am doing this for every month but I want to know how I can resolve this without any intervention every month

Comment: Fix your processing so you insert each month's data into a single table.  That is the RIGHT way to address this issue.  Proliferate rows not tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for this solution, you must have same fields in your dynamic tables.

Tablename can be anything in your database, this will works for all tablenames.

Try this if you get your results.

```
declare @table table([Name] varchar(200))
declare @query VARCHAR(max)
declare @strQuery varchar(max) = '';
set @query='SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES';
insert into @table exec (@query)
--select * from @table (You will get all your table names)

declare @tablename varchar(100)
declare @i int=0

DECLARE curFetchData CURSOR FOR SELECT [Name] from @table
OPEN curFetchData          
    FETCH NEXT FROM curFetchData INTO @tablename
    WHILE @@Fetch_status = 0          
    BEGIN   
        IF(@i>0)        
            set @strQuery = @strQuery + (' UNION ALL ')     
        set @strQuery = @strQuery + (' SELECT * from '+@tablename+' ')
        set @i=@i+1;
    FETCH NEXT FROM curFetchData INTO @tablename
    END 
CLOSE curFetchData
DEALLOCATE curFetchData
PRINT (@strQuery)
EXEC (@strQuery)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this query. Please ensure the input parameter.

```
DECLARE @inputYear INT,@tablename VARCHAR(20)=''
SET @inputYear =2019---- year(getdate())

DECLARE @v nvarchar(30)='TRNS%'+right(convert(varchar(4),@inputyear),2)

DECLARE @query nvarchar(max)=''
SELECT @query=@query+' UNION ALL SELECT * FROM ' +  NAME from sys.tables where name like @v
SELECT @query= STUFF(@query,1,10,'')
EXECUTE sp_executesql @query
```